# How to make All Folders, Sub-Folders & Files Read-Only EXCEPT for 4 Sub-Folders in a File Share?

Tags: powershell, fileshare

I need some help!
Heres the scenerio;
I need to make all Files & Folders on one of our File Shares Read-Only except for 4 Sub-Folders accross many different folders on the share. All Level 1 Sub-Folders have same 4 folders within and those permissions need to be preserved while all others need to be set to Read-Only.

I wrote up the script below and all is working fine to Exclude the 4 Sub-Folders when setting to Read-Only, but when I add the -Recurse switch to Get-ChildItem the Exclude list is ignored for some reason.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$Path = C:\Users\Username\Downloads\*
$Exclude = "\Sub-Folder1\*","\Sub-Folder2\*","\Sub-Folder3\*","\Sub-Folder4\*"
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Exclude $Exclude
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) {

             Set-ItemProperty -Path $Folder -Name IsReadOnly -Value $True -Exclude $Exclude
             Write-Host folder:$Folder IsReadOnly: $Folder.IsReadOnly
          }
```

I was expecting that the Attribute would be changed on all Folders and Files Except for what I placed in the Exclude list.

Comment: Use just the name without any directory markings: `$exclude = 'Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3', 'Folder4'`

Comment: Also keep in mind that the folders that you specify will be excluded, but the files within them will not be. So it will exclude 'C:\Temp\Sub-Folder1' but will not exclude 'C:\Temp\Sub-Folder1\Employees.xlsx'. It may be better to do `$Exclude = 'Sub-Folder1|Sub-Folder2|Sub-Folder3|Sub-Folder4'` then `$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.FullName -notmatch $Exclude}`